# error importing com.google.android.gms.*;

Tags: java, android, sdk, google-api, importerror

I am trying to implement the solution in [link](http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html)

Require to import these:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;  
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks; 
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener; import com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionClient;
```

**i cannot compile because eclipse does not recognize**

```
 "com.google.android.gms."......
```

**Have also updated the SDK and the google API to the latest (4.3)**

Still not able to import the package.

Comment: Is the lib GMS in your build path ?

Comment: thak you man, but i successed :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Follow this [guide](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Install) to setup the Google Play Services SDK. It's a client library which you have to get from the SDK Manager. After you downloaded it, add the library as a project.

Answer (score 3):

1. Import Google Play service as `C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services`
2. Select libproject
3. Select your project, go to properties, and under Android add Google Play service library.

NOTE:  you have to install Google Play service from SDK Manager.

Answer (score 1):

To add to all the answers, make sure the android-support-v4.jar is same in both the MainProject and library project. If they are found to be different, the library project jars to not get added to your apk and you can get class not found error.