# what is the dependency for import com.google.android.gms.common.util.CrashUtils.ErrorDialogData

Tags: java, android

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.util.CrashUtils.ErrorDialogData;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    int itemId = menuItem.getItemId();
    if (itemId == R.id.action_home) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), QuoreMain.class);
        intent.setFlags(ErrorDialogData.BINDER_CRASH);
        startActivity(intent, ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(this.eDContext, 
        R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right).toBundle());
        this.eActivity.finish();
        return true;
        } 
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }
}
```

I am working with `ErrorDialogData.BINDER_CRASH` but it does not import the class.
What is the dependency for `import com.google.android.gms.common.util.CrashUtils.ErrorDialogData;`

Comment: Please next time add detail to [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872829/what-is-the-dependency-for-import-com-google-android-gms-common-util-crashutils) instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error importing com.google.android.gms.\*;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853403/error-importing-com-google-android-gms)

Answer (score -1):

I has been already answered here: [error importing com.google.android.gms.*;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853403/error-importing-com-google-android-gms)

Follow [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#Install) guide to setup the Google Play Services SDK. It's a client library which you have to get from the SDK Manager. After you downloaded it, add the library as a project.

Comment: Instead of answering, mark this question as a duplicate!

Comment: Did both, check it first. Thanks for down vote, definitely learned a lesson here..

Comment: please tell me the dependency, I want only dependency.